# How to customize theme in BigBlueButton for Login, Register and HomePage

Tags: java, bigbluebutton

I'm using BigBlueButton on Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to customize the theme used for Login, Register, and Homepage (I will add a new interface). Editing the existing template would be sufficient for me. I've read a lot of articles but none of them provided a solution. I don't know how to do this. Can you help?